# What is idiomatic clojure to validate that a string has only alphanumerics and hyphen?

Tags: regex, string, validation, clojure

I need to ensure that a certain input only contains lowercase alphas and hyphens.  What's the best idiomatic clojure to accomplish that?

In JavaScript I would do something like this:

```
if (str.match(/^[a-z\-]+$/)) { ... }
```

What's a more idiomatic way in clojure, or if this is it, what's the syntax for regex matching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
user> (re-matches #"^[a-z\-]+$" "abc-def")
"abc-def"
user> (re-matches #"^[a-z\-]+$" "abc-def!!!!")
nil
user> (if (re-find #"^[a-z\-]+$" "abc-def")
        :found)
:found
user> (re-find #"^[a-zA-Z]+" "abc.!@#@#@123")
"abc"
user> (re-seq #"^[a-zA-Z]+" "abc.!@#@#@123")
("abc")
user> (re-find #"\w+" "0123!#@#@#ABCD")
"0123"
user> (re-seq #"\w+" "0123!#@#@#ABCD")
("0123" "ABCD")
```

Comment: Well, since you already edited in `re-matches` you could also strip `^...$` from the regex supplied to it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using RegExp is fine here. To match a string with RegExp in clojure you may use [build-in `re-find` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-find).

So, your example in clojure will look like:

```
(if (re-find #"^[a-z\-]+$" s)
    :true
    :false)
```

Note that your RegExp will match only small latyn letters `a-z` and hyphen `-`.

Answer (score 2):

While `re-find` surely is an option, `re-matches` is what you'd want for matching a whole string without having to provide `^...$` wrappers:

```
(re-matches #"[-a-z]+" "hello-there")
;; => "hello-there"

(re-matches #"[-a-z]+" "hello there")
;; => nil
```

So, your if-construct could look like this:

```
(if (re-matches #"[-a-z]+" s)
  (do-something-with s)
  (do-something-else-with s))
```